# How the local and member variable behaves in Objective C - IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have not clear how Objective C handle the local and member variable, as I am new to this.
 Consider I am creating a view inside a function like this...

```
fun () {
   new_class *var = [new_class alloc] init]

   // some code to push the view here...
}
```

everything works fine here, now my question is var is a local variable, when the function scope ends, will it die or not? if it dies how the view is working properly when I am doing some action in it...

thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The var should be release, if it doesn't have other objects point at it. The thing is:

```
if it dies how the view is working properly when I am doing some action in it
```

If your "var" is an `UIView` for instance, and you `[self.view addSubview:var]`, now you have two objects pointing at it: `*var` and your `self.view`, that's why everything is ok.

Comment: So if I push view through navigation controller, it will increase its reference count right?

Answer (score 2):

The *pointer* `var` will go out of scope and be "deleted", but the *object* to which it points won't be deleted until it is later released (either manually or through ARC, if enabled).

Answer (score 1):

No it won't die. The variable is scoped local to the function, so the compiler won't let you access `var` outside your fun() method, however you will have a memory leak (assuming no ARC)

You've allocated memory, but haven't released it.

You can release it manually, or make use of the AutoReleasePool and have it release when the pool is drained.

In newer version of IOS, Apple has added support for Automatic Reference Counting (ARC), where the compiler will add the `[obj release];` statements for you.

From the comments:

If you have an object that is placed on a stack, and you later want to release it. When you pop the UIView, a pointer to that view is returned. If you assign that to some local variable, you can release it when you are ready to:

```
UIView * myView = [someViewHandler popView]; 
[myView release]; myView = nil;
```

Comment: His last sentence implies that he lets the variable leave the function scope somehow (though I may be mistaken...)

Comment: I am using ARC, If it is a non-ARC how can we delete or release a local var, because it is accessible only to that function.

Comment: For manual memory management, use: `[var release]; var = nil;`

Comment: @Alan No, you are not understood my question, var is local to that function, if I popped that view I don't need any more I have to release that object, so var is not accessible for me, because it is limited to that function, in that case, how can we delete that var?

Comment: how can i know whether the ARC is enable?

Comment: @danzen: If you try to manually release memory when ARC is enabled, the compiler will throw an error.